# How to obtain an always fixed header in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, position, toolbar, fixed

I have implemented a fixed header in jQuery Mobile, and it's working great for the most part. When I scroll, the toolbar remains visible. When I tap the screen, the header does not disappear. Great. The only annoyance I see is that when you tap into an input field that's towards the bottom of the page, the header then reverts to `position:static` so it disappears. You can see that by scrolling back up to the top. Once you unfocus the input box (hit done on the keyboard), then it goes back to `position:fixed`. I would like it to always be visible no matter what.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

I'm using jQM 1.4.0 RC1 and in the change log it states:
- Fixed Toolbars are now an extension on the toolbar widget
Sounds relevant, but I'm not sure what exactly that means.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This actually a fix for many issues raised on `fixedtoolbar` widget.

1. [Issue #4410](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4410)
2. [Issue #4724](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4724)

jQM hides fixed toolbars once `focus` is triggered on `select`, `textarea` and `select`; to give more working place when screen width less than **1025**.

I have tried the below solution but the results were ugly.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.hideDuringFocus = "";
  });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
```

For more details, check [fixedToolbar.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/831e5657443a31f1199956a989fb5ce12672d15f/js/widgets/fixedToolbar.js) widget on GitHub, go to line **243**.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/23Bx4/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1) To be tested on Mobile browsers, not desktop.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the demo Omar. Unfortunately, changing hideDuringFocus didn't prevent the header from hiding on focus. Tested on Mobile Safari - iOS 7.

Comment: @Joey I know, I've mentioned that in my answer. jQM made this to fix issues with native keyboard on iOS and Android.

Comment: I thought the purpose of setting `hideDuringFocus` to an empty string was an attempt to work around that behavior and force it always visible, which isn't the case. It behaves the same whether or not you add that code. Wonder if those bugs are fixed in iOS 7 and newer android versions, but if not then I'll deal with sometimes hidden headers.

Comment: If you test my demo on iPhone, click on inout then scroll, you'll find that the header is visible but misplaced. iOS 7 keyboard height is approx. 288px, it pushes the header that far. @Joey

Comment: Oh I see. That's rather unfortunate.